# How to print GWC layer?

Tags: geoserver, printing

I have GWC layer on my GeoServer. Now I want to  print this layer using GeoServer print module but don't know how to do this.

When I try WMS layer all works fine. But how to print the GWC layer?

**MORE INFO**

In client side I have a GXP and try to print using gxp_print plugin. My problem is that I can't set URL to the GWC layer.

I read [this](http://www.geoext.org/pipermail/users/2011-August/002533.html) and [this](https://getsatisfaction.com/opengeo/topics/problem_printing_geowebcache_layers_in_geoexplorer): so I try this URL:

```
layer.setUrl("/geoserver/gwc/service/wms?BBOX=7637927.0361051%2C6845332.4516735%2C7750900.9638949%2C6971453.5483265&HEIGHT=256&WIDTH=256&TRANSPARENT=true&map_resolution=305.74811309814453&VERSION=1.1.1&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TILED=true&SERVICE=WMS&format_options=dpi%3A100&LAYERS=gisurfo:atd&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG%3A900913&");
```

But GeoServer returns me error:

```
400: Requested horizontal resolution: 441.30440542890574 , best match: 
305.74811309814453 exceeds 10% threshold. Perhaps the client is configured with an 
incorrect set of scales (resolutions), or the DPI setting is off compared to the one in GWC ?
```

This same like in links above. So how to print GWC?

**UPDATE**

Good news. I changed scales in my `config.yaml` file to scales that I get from the GWC layer (but I get only left part of each scale). Now I try to print GWC layer but it not printing. In GeoServer log I found Bad Request:

```
java.io.IOException: Error (status=400) while reading the image from 
http://geourfo.ru:9091/geoserver/gwc/service/wms?BBOX=6866019.0%2C7636631.0%2C6950767.0%2C7752196.5    &HEIGHT=625&WIDTH=458&VERSION=1.1.1&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&SERVICE=WMS&
format_options=dpi%3A75&LAYERS=gisurfo%3Aatd&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG%3A900913
: Bad Request
```

After I change width and height to 256/256 and get my tile!

So question: why iprint plugin take tiles with HEIGHT=625 and WIDTH=458 but not with 256x256?

Comment: Any solution so far? I´m going throught the same problem at the moment